# Conversion of height systems

Tags: coordinate-system, tiles, cesium

If I have a vector dataset with *XYZ* data and convert it with QGIS from EPSG:31468 to EPSG:4979, for example, and the heights (z) are based on EPSG:31468.

Will these values also be converted to the EPSG:4979 height system (i.e. based on the WGS84 ellipsoid) during the conversion?

My source data comes from the first EPSG while I want to display the converted data in Cesiumjs, which only supports the second EPSG, and the heights are relevant.

Comment: The geodetic base CRS for EPSG:31468 is 2D. Also, I think that QGIS do not manage 3D geodetic CRS, so maybe you cannot convert your vector dataset with QGIS to EPSG:4979.